# Dudas de como crear 2 ramas principales en un proyecto angular

Tags: angular

A la hora de realizar el código no se como crear correctamente las ramas hijas (routing) de la segunda rama principal. Por una lado tengo la rama padre "Home" de la que descienden todos los módulos y quiero crear una "Help" al mismo nivel con otros módulos, no se si tengo que crear otro "app-routing.module.ts" para que haga las mismas funciones junto con su "app.module.ts" pero con otros nombres

Answer (score 0):

Se llama routing y si quieres usarlo a través de módulos debes utilizar lazi loading para poder llamar a los componentes hijos. Esto te dará una mejora en el tiempo de carga y en la organización de tus componentes.

Suponiendo que quieres crear un nuevo `pages.module` deberias ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
ng g m pages/pages --route laRutaQueQuieras  --module app.module
```

Esto creara en tu routing de `app-routing.module` (en caso de que lo tengas fuera de tu modulo, si no será dentro) la siguiente linea:

```
{
    path: 'prueba', //Lo puedes dejar en blanco para que sea el principal
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/pages.module').then(
        m => m.PagesModule
      )
  },
```

Esto se repite igual si quieres crear más módulos hijos de `pages.module`:

```
ng g m pages/home --route home --module pages.module
```

La creación de componentes es igual que siempre, solo que hay que señalar el directorio.

```
ng g c pages/home/menu
```

Esto provocara que se registre el componente en dicho modulo. Solo te restaría registrar el componente al routing.

Tu caso quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  path: 'home', //Lo puedes dejar en blanco para que sea el principal
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('./pages/home/home.module').then(
      m => m.PagesModule
    )
},

{
  path: 'help',
  loadChildren: () =>
    import ('./pages/help/help.module').then(
      m => m.PagesModule
    )
},
```

En caso de que sean componentes reutilizables pues crear el modulo fuera de `pages.module` e importarlo en cualquier modulo.

### La forma que no recomiendo

Suponiendo que este sea tu routing, puedes lograr lo que quieres sin lazy loading solo modificando el path.

```
{
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
}, {
  path: 'usuario/confirmar',
  component: UsuarioConfirmarComponent
}, {
  path: 'usuario/detalles',
  component: UsuarioDetallesComponent
}

{
  path: 'usuario/detalles/masDetallado',
  component: UsuarioDetallesMasDetalladoComponent
}
```

Comment: Cuando creas un componente le puedes especificar un módulo, así te evitas andar modificando archivos luego. Por otra parte... no se recomienda responder preguntas que no tengan un mínimo de trabajo de investigación, porque acabará cerrada.

Comment: Con la ruta del modulo, CLI automáticamente detecta y registra el componente sin más problemas. No me parece poco clara. Es una pregunta sencilla y creo haber entendido bien el punto. Aunque se cierre, la respuesta puede ser útil.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por que votar negativamente.

Comment: Si sabes que puedes reabrir la pregunta?

Comment: *Lo que no entiendo es por que votar negativamente.* -> Te explico por qué lo hago. Si la gente sigue respondiendo preguntas formuladas por gente con 0 interés en la comunidad, atraeremos más y más preguntas de ese estilo puesto que "Para qué voy a esforzarme en escribir una buena pregunta si me la van a responder igualmente". Por supuesto que la respuesta puede ser válida igualmente, pero es muy difícil que otra persona con la misma duda se identifique con la pregunta si apenas puede entenderla. En cambio una pregunta bien explicada es más fácil de buscar... y encontrar :)

Comment: @Christian Si, he votado. Gracias por recordarmelo.

Comment: @Benito-B Entiendo tu punto, agradezco la corrección y la amabilidad. Sin embargo, este se me hizo un caso puntual y fácil de resolver. Por eso la respuesta. No necesitaba más información. Aunque estoy de acuerdo que la pregunta puede ser más clara.